# Angular: CanDeactivate guard put on the routing of a lazy loaded module does not trigger at all

Tags: angular

In my application I have some deep nested routings that are like this:

```
<router-outlet>
    <router-outlet name="something">
        <router-outlet>
            <component-to-guard></<component-to-guard>
        </router-outlet>
    </router-outlet>
</router-outlet>
```

All of the levels have lazy loaded module and routings, including the first and main router outlet of the application. What I am trying to achieve is to add a "canDeactivate" guard on the  route, so when I leave it and have unsaved changes I am not allowed to.

The problem I encounter is that the guard I've added, both with the old CanDeactivate extend class way, with the inject() functional way by injecting a class or by calling a function on the component directly do not work. By not working meaning the canDeactivate never triggers at all, no breakpoints is ever triggered, yet I receive no errors, the navigation simply happens with or without the guard like it is not there.

This is how my navigations to that component-to-guard looks like:

```
   {
    path: 'settings',
    loadChildren: () => import('@modules/settings.module').then((m) => m.SettingsModule),
   },


   // Settings Module routing. AppMainSettingsComponent will load in the first router-outlet
   path: '',
   component: AppMainSettingsComponent,
   children: [
     {
       path: 'screenConfigTab',
       loadChildren: () => import('@modules/screenConfigTab.module').then((m) => m.ScreenConfigTabModule),
       outlet: 'something',
     },
   ]


   // Screen Config Tab Module routing. ScreenConfigurationMainComponent will load in the second router-outlet
   path: '',
   component: ScreenConfigurationMainComponent,
   children: [
     {
        path: 'manualConfig',
        loadChildren: () => import('@modules/settings-modules/heatmapConfig.module').then((m) => m.HeatmapConfigModules),
     },
   ]


   // HeatmapConfigModules routing (and the only routing). Will load into the third router-outlet
   {
      path: '',
      component: GridManagementWindowComponent,
      canDeactivate: [(component: GridManagementWindowComponent) => component.hasUnsavedChanges()],
    },
```

And here lies the problem, in the last routing. No matter what navigation I do or how, hasUnsavedChanges() never triggers, neither any breakpoint in canDeactivate itself.

Having something like this also does not work

```
   canDeactivate: [() => inject(GridUnsavedGuard).canDeactivate()],
```

Where GridUnsavedGuard exists, it has @Injectable() also (with or without it it does not matter though, still does not work, it never goes into it).

And neither this

```
   canDeactivate: [GridUnsavedGuard],
```

Where GridUnsavedGuard extends CanDeactivate with the GridManagementWindowComponent component and is provided in either root or the HeatmapConfigModules module. Still does not work, nothing triggers at all.

Is this a bug of Angular? The weird thing is that canActivate guards work, if I put a canActivate guard on that route it will trigger correctly in all cases. Only canDeactivate does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue as  you. Above guard setup has solved my issue. The problem is angular **Deactivate** hits twice while executes. So using promise inside the guard is the best solution. I have used Primeng confirm dialog to show the confirmation modal.

```
export class RouteChangeGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
        
            private isFirstEvent: boolean = true;
           
      constructor(private confirmationService: ConfirmationService) {
      }
              canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
            
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                  if(this.isFirstEvent) {
                    this.isFirstEvent = false;
                    resolve(true)
                  }
                  this.confirmationService.confirm({
                    message: 'Are you sure that you want to proceed?',
                    header: 'Confirmation',
                    icon: 'pi pi-exclamation-triangle',
                    accept: () => {
                      resolve(true)
                    },
                    reject: () => {
                     resolve(false)
                    },
                  })
                });
            
              }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that you have properly implemented the **canDeactivate**

```
export class MyComponent implements CanDeactivate<MyComponent> {
  canDeactivate(): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page?');
  }
}
```

Ensure that you have added the **canDeactivate**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'my-component',
    component: MyComponent,
    canDeactivate: [MyGuard]
  }
];
```

Ensure that you have properly imported the **CanDeactivate interface** and your guard in your module file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';
import { MyGuard } from './my.guard';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MyComponent,
    canDeactivate: [MyGuard]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MyModule { }
```

Comment: All of this was done already, still does not work